# How to fix the gap in between elements in the form?

Tags: html, forms, css, flexbox

The `flexbox` form has gap in between form items when there is radio button or checkbox. Is there any option to avoid the gap whether using flex or any other method?

```css
form {
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

form>div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 50%;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

form>div input:not([type=checkbox]):not([type=radio]),
form>div textarea {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 0.25rem;
  min-height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div><input placeholder="First Name" /></div>
  <div><input placeholder="Last Name" /></div>
  <div>
    <ul class="radio_list">
      <li><input name="form" type="radio" value="0">&nbsp;<label>Male</label></li>
      <li><input name="form" type="radio" value="1">&nbsp;<label>Female</label></li>
      <li><input name="form" type="radio" value="2">&nbsp;<label>gfdg</label></li>
      <li><input name="form" type="radio" value="3">&nbsp;<label>gfdg</label></li>
      <li><input name="form" type="radio" value="4">&nbsp;<label>gfd</label></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div><input placeholder="Phone" type="phone" /></div>
  <div><input placeholder="Email" type="email" /></div>
  <div>
    <ul class="checkbox_list">
      <li><input name="form_3" type="checkbox" value="0" checked="checked" required="required">&nbsp;<label>Checkbox 1</label></li>
      <li><input name="form_3" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked">&nbsp;<label>Checkbox 2</label></li>
      <li><input name="form_3" type="checkbox" value="2" checked="checked">&nbsp;<label>Checkbox 3</label></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div><textarea rows="4" cols="30" placeholder="Coment"></textarea></div>
</form>
```

Comment: What about apply flex: 1 only to the elements you need. Like input box, textarea, etc.

Comment: you can reset the *default* `margin` and `padding` to zero for the `ul` that contains the radio button & checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `column` for this. check updated snippet below

```css
form {
  width: 100%;
  float: left; 
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2; 
    column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 0.5rem;
}
form > div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  break-inside: avoid;

}
form > div input:not([type=checkbox]):not([type=radio]),
form > div textarea {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 0.25rem;
  min-height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div><input placeholder="First Name" /></div>
  <div><input placeholder="Last Name" /></div>
  <div>
    <ul class="radio_list">
      <li><input name="form" type="radio" value="0">&nbsp;<label>Male</label></li>
      <li><input name="form" type="radio" value="1">&nbsp;<label>Female</label></li>
      <li><input name="form" type="radio" value="2">&nbsp;<label>gfdg</label></li>
      <li><input name="form" type="radio" value="3">&nbsp;<label>gfdg</label></li>
      <li><input name="form" type="radio" value="4">&nbsp;<label>gfd</label></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div><input placeholder="Phone" type="phone" /></div>
  <div><input placeholder="Email" type="email" /></div>
  <div>
    <ul class="checkbox_list">
      <li><input name="form_3" type="checkbox" value="0" checked="checked" required="required">&nbsp;<label>Checkbox 1</label></li>
      <li><input name="form_3" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked">&nbsp;<label>Checkbox 2</label></li>
      <li><input name="form_3" type="checkbox" value="2" checked="checked">&nbsp;<label>Checkbox 3</label></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div><textarea rows="4" cols="30" placeholder="Coment"></textarea></div>
</form>
```

Comment: nice answer, but what if I need the `textarea` needs in full width ?

Comment: @SuoerUser that is also part my question. however yo gave nice solution so far :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS grid [check out the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x1q7rkov/1/)

Note: I have also rearranged the checkbox div

```
form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
}
```

You can specify the rowspan and colspan with CSS grid

```
.span-col {
  grid-column: span 2
}

.span-row {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

I have added the **span-col** class to the textarea div, if you remove the class it will align in 2 columns.

Read more about : [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)